# Too large files when downloading Piktogramms

Tags: java, url, filestream

I'm trying to download some images provided by a hoster. This is the method I use:

```
public static void downloadImage(String imageLink, File f) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(imageLink);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), buffer.length);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f), buffer.length);

    while (in.read(buffer) > 0)
        out.write(buffer);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

However, the file turn out too big. 5MB for a 80x60 jpg is too  much in my opinion.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: do yourself a favor and use a library for that. My favorite for stream copy is Apache Commons IOUtils (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: You are welcome; thanks for the quick accept.

Comment: And side note; I agree with Thomas: unless this is some "education exercise" - you are better of using some library to do that.

Comment: @GhostCat Right now I'm still being educated, so I want to understand as many aspects of java as possible without using libraries, but I'll also take this advice to my heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things wrong here: read() returns the number of bytes that were really read; thus you have to write exactly that number from your buffer array into your output stream.

Your code is corrupting your output; and simply writing out a buffer array ... that mostly consists of 0s!

Instead do something like:

```
int bytesRead;
while ( ( bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
   byte outBuffer[] = new byte[bytesRead];
   ... then use arraycopy to move bytesRead bytes
   out.write(outBuffer);
}
```

( this is meant as inspiration to get you going, more pseudo like than real code )

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to remember this fact